# I want to update my document fields in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is Code

```
holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final DialogPlus dialogPlus=DialogPlus.newDialog(holder.btnEdit.getContext())
                .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.update_popup))
                .setExpanded(Boolean.parseBoolean("true"),1200)
                .create();

        //dialogPlus.show();

        View v =dialogPlus.getHolderView();
        EditText name=v.findViewById(R.id.editName);
        EditText fname=v.findViewById(R.id.editFName);
        EditText Department=v.findViewById(R.id.editdepartment);
        EditText RollNo=v.findViewById(R.id.editroll);
        EditText phone=v.findViewById(R.id.editphone);
        EditText email=v.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        EditText address=v.findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        EditText password=v.findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

        Button btnUpdate = v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);


        name.setText(student.getName());
        fname.setText(student.getFName());
        Department.setText(student.getDepartment());
        RollNo.setText(student.getRollno());
        phone.setText(student.getPhone());
        email.setText(student.getEmail());
        address.setText(student.getAddress());
        password.setText(student.getPass());

        dialogPlus.show();

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("Name",name.getText().toString());
                map.put("FName",fname.getText().toString());
                map.put("Department",Department.getText().toString());
                map.put("Rollno",RollNo.getText().toString());
                map.put("phone",phone.getText().toString());
                map.put("Email",email.getText().toString());
                map.put("address",address.getText().toString());
                map.put("pass",password.getText().toString());



                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                FirebaseFirestore firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();



                 firestore.collection("Student").document(user.getUid()).update(map)
                         .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                             }
                         });
```

Like in Real time Database it would be

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Student").child(getRef(Position).key)).updateChildren(map)`

How I can do it in Firestore?

Comment: That code looks fine at first glance. What is the problem when you execute it?

Comment: Getting this error                                                                                      
         /AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.husmarttrack, PID: 15195
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
        at

Comment: Application crashed after pressing update button

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never initialize `mAuth`.

You probably need something like this in your `onCreate`:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Also see the documentation on [getting started with Firebase Authentication on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start#check_current_auth_state), from which that code comes.

Comment: Sir mAuth is already define ..Actually I want to update my firestore Data I know how to do in firebase but don't know how to do in firestore I added the above code but App crashed...

Comment: to update firebase data we do something like this....||CODE______FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Student").child(getRef(Position).key)).updateChildren(map).firestore.collection("Student").document(user.getUid()).update(map)

Comment: If `mAuth` was initialized already, you wouldn't get "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference"